# Mostrar/Abrir imagen en modal por ID

Tags: php, html, mysql

tengo una tabla que me muestra los datos por fila con su id
respectivo, modificar,eliminar, nuevo, pero ¿Cómo hago para que me
muestre la imagen o foto por ID pero en un modal? estoy trabajando en
un codigo pero solo me muestra el modal y el campo de la foto vacío¿?

```html
<td> <a href="#"   data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Modal4"><img src="<?php echo $row['ruta'] ?>" /></a></td>
```

```html
<div class="modal" id="Modal4" name="#Modal4" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
 <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
   <div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-header">
    <h5 class="modal-title">Aubrey Drake "Drizzy" Graham</h5>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
<img src="<?php echo $row['ruta'] ?>" style="width:130px;height:140px;margin-left:10px;margin-bottom:10px" />
</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Si me puedierán ayudar

Comment: Buenas. ¿Has probado a hacer el echo fuera de la imagen (o inspeccionar el elemento img) para ver qué te está llegando en $row['ruta'] por si ahí estuviera el problema?

Comment: hola,  <td><img src="<?php echo $row['ruta'] ?>" width="40px" height="40px" /> asi lo tengo en tabla y se visualiza la imagen correctamente, pero se ve algo no llamativo, me gustaria agregar un boton o un icono que cuando se presione muestra la imagen en un modal.

Comment: Ok. Me refiero a qué valor tiene "ruta", una propiedad de $row, que imagino es una file del resultado de una consulta a una base de datos.

Comment: Hola @Noveember ¿estas usando Bootstrap? Si la respuesta es sí ¿que versión?

Comment: Bootstrap  v5.2.3

Comment: ¿Cuál es el valor de `$row['ruta']`? Pon un `var_dump($row['ruta']);` y dinos qué muestra.

Comment: <td><img src="<?php echo $row['ruta'] ?>" width="40px" height="40px" /> con este muestro la imagen pero deberia pasar la id "<?php echo $row['id'] ?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes colocar un modal **en cada fila**. Como nombre del modal puedes usar algo como:

```
id="modal<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"
```

La idea es que cada modal tenga un nombre diferente (también podrías usar un contador, como el que a veces se coloca en la columna llamada No. de una tabla). Y en el botón lo llamas usando el mismo nombre:

```
data-target="#modal<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
```

De esa manera cada modal tendrá un nombre único y como estás dentro de la fila, puedes mostrar en él los datos que ya recuperaste para esa fila.

Comment: LISTO YA RESOLVI COMO MOSTRAR LA IMAGEN POR MODAL MEDIANTE ID, TU EJEMPLO ME HICO COMPLETAR LO QUE ME FALTABA